# When is a web server such as Apache needed?

Tags: apache, webserver

So I'm in my last semester of college. I'm majoring in IT. For my senior project I'm building a website which is going to be an online shop for a family members home business. My advisor has asked me what platforms I'm using.
Two questions.
First - Somehow I have no idea what a platform is or why it is needed. I don't get why I cannot just upload my .html files to a site. Say I buy a godaddy domain, can't I just upload(FTP) these files instead of having to use a 'platform'. Also what are the popular platforms so I can go take a look at them and figure out what I'm missing.

Second - When is something such as Apache needed? I've used Apache before for a PHP class but why is it really necessary.

I'm rather stunned I don't know the answer to this question. I'm starting to feel like I've completely missed something here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hosting arrangements, and not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is the software the runs on your server and handles web requests and serves your HTML files in response. It also handles requests for PHP files and serves the response it gets from a PHP script. There are other web servers available, but Apache is one of the most popular. Without a web server you don't have a web site. If you buy a domain from GoDaddy or wherever, they will be running Apache or something similar on their servers to provide the web site service.

Additionally, if you're trying to build an online store you'll need some sort of scripting language, and a database. The common solution for these is PHP and MySQL, although other solutions are not uncommon.

However, if you need to ask questions like this I'd suggest your web skills are a long way from what is required to build a successful and *secure* site. You would probably do better to look at a ready built system - there are plenty of decent, and free, systems available. Google is your friend.

Comment: Beat me to it. I would add that obtaining a domain is only helpful if you were planning on hosting the site. As is, there may be several hosting solutions that might suit the OP's needs.